# How to resolve the Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell and Get-TfsChildItem error?

Tags: powershell, tfs

Below is the PowerShell Script that I am using to download the folder from TFS 2013 Update 4 to my local machine but i am getting some exception which I have copied below the code.

```
$AutoDeployDir = "$/Intel/Installscript/Utility Scripts"
$deployDirectory = "C:\powershell scripts\New folder\Demo TFS Code"

# Add TFS 2013 dlls so we can download some files
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client")
$tfsCollectionUrl = "http://stptfs2013dbsvr:8080/tfs/intelcollection"
$tfsCollection = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection -ArgumentList $tfsCollectionUrl
$tfsVersionControl = $tfsCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])

# Register PowerShell commands
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell

# Get all directories and files in the AutoDeploy directory
$items = Get-TfsChildItem $AutoDeployDir -Recurse -Server $tfsCollection

# Download each item to a specific destination
foreach ($item in $items) {
    # Serverpath of the item
    Write-Host "TFS item to download:" $($item.ServerItem) -ForegroundColor Blue

    $destinationPath = $item.ServerItem.Replace($AutoDeployDir, $deployDirectory)
    Write-Host "Download to" $([IO.Path]::GetFullPath($destinationPath)) -ForegroundColor Blue

    if ($item.ItemType -eq "Folder") {
        New-Item $([IO.Path]::GetFullPath($destinationPath)) -ItemType Directory -Force
    }
    else {
        # Download the file (not folder) to destination directory
        $tfsVersionControl.DownloadFile($item.ServerItem, $([IO.Path]::GetFullPath($destinationPath)))
    }
}
```

Exception that occurs is:

```
Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.
At C:\powershell scripts\demo1.ps1:12 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand

Get-TfsChildItem : The term 'Get-TfsChildItem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\powershell scripts\demo1.ps1:15 char:10
+ $items = Get-TfsChildItem $AutoDeployDir -Recurse -Server $tfsCollection
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-TfsChildItem:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you have fully installed the [TFS Powertools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2013Power).

By default it doesn’t install the **PowerShell CmdLets**. If it is, just install it and then the issue will be gone.

Another possibility is that the PowerShell Snap-in is stored in the inconsistent  registry with the OS version (32bit/64bit).

> PowerTools installer is 32bit, on 64bit machine, it will write to
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns`,
>   but not to
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns.`

Reference this similar thread for details: [TFS Power Tools 2008 Powershell Snapin won’t run in on 64-bit in Windows 2008 R2?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a116799a-0476-4c42-aa3e-45d8ba23739e/tfs-power-tools-2008-powershell-snapin-wont-run-in-on-64bit-in-windows-2008-r2?forum=tfspowertools)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now I am using another code to download the files from TFS which does not use "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell"